# SQL pivot for a rows that have multiple attribute name in one column and multiple values in another rows in another column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have one column whose rows are formatted with attributenames and another columns have with values, such

```
SourceTechAttributesName
MediaFormat, FrameRate, DropFrame, StartSmpte
MediaFormat, FrameRate, DropFrame, StartSmpte
MediaFormat, FrameRate, DropFrame, StartSmpte
MediaFormat, NativeFrameRate, ActionType, ViewportDisplayFormat, ViewportAspectRatio, FrameRate, Width, Height, ScanType, FieldDominance, DropFrame, NativeFieldOrder, CadencePattern, NumberOfAudioChannels, NumberOfAudioTracks, StartSmpte, Duration
MediaFormat, NativeFrameRate, ActionType, ViewportDisplayFormat, ViewportAspectRatio, FrameRate, Width, Height, ScanType, FieldDominance, DropFrame, NativeFieldOrder, CadencePattern, NumberOfAudioChannels, NumberOfAudioTracks, StartSmpte, Duration
```

And Another column has values such as

SourceTechAttributesValue

```
96, 29.97, False, 00:00:00:00
96, 29.97, False, 00:00:00:00
96, 29.97, False, 00:00:00:00
645, 23.98, Live Action, Anamorphic, 1.78:1 (16x9), 23.98, 1920, 1080, Progressive, Lower Field First, False, Progressive, 2-2, 12, 12, 00:59:35:00, 1507.380875
645, 23.98, Live Action, Anamorphic, 1.78:1 (16x9), 23.98, 1920, 1080, Progressive, Lower Field First, False, Progressive, 2-2, 12, 12, 00:59:35:00, 1507.380875
```

I want to have pivot out that in below format

```
srcMediaFormat srcFrameRate srcDropFrame srcWidth srcHeight srcCodec srcDuration
    96           29.97       FALSE              
    644          23.98       FALSE        1920     1080               1646.645
    644          23.98       FALSE        1920     1080               1626.625
```

I know how to do if there only one attribute would have in that column and one value in different column such as

```
pivot
(
    max(SourceTechAttributeValue)
    for SourceTechAttributeName in ([srcMediaFormat],[srcFrameRate],[srcDropFrame],[srcWidth],[srcHeight],[srcCodec],[srcDuration])

    )piv
```

But because of each column has multiple attributeName and attributValue, I cannot able to achieve my goal.I want to be result out like below

```
srcMediaFormat srcFrameRate srcDropFrame srcWidth srcHeight srcCodec srcDuration
        96           29.97       FALSE              
        644          23.98       FALSE        1920     1080               1646.645
        644          23.98       FALSE        1920     1080               1626.625
```

Can anyone please help me to accomplish this achievement.Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Are SourceTechAttributesName and SourceTechAttributesValue delimited strings?

Comment: well data for that columns are much same  as above, the SourceTechAttributeName has multiple attribute name by comma separated and SourceTechAttributeValue has those attributes value in same format. see the above, think about that two columns in SQL with those attribute name and values and results we want to achieve the format which I have mentioned  in the questions, pivot column would be MediaFormat, FrameRate, DropFrame, StartSmpte, etc and their values would be 96, 29.97, False, 00:00:00:00. Thanks for your quick response @D-Shih

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Yes both columns are nvarchar type but the rows inside SourceTechAttributeValue has different datatype as both two columns has struct from Stuff function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of a Parse/Split function which returns a sequence as well as a value.  We first UNPIVOT your data, and then perform a simple PIVOT.

I should add, it is a small matter to replace `[dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse]()` with a subquery.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SourceTechAttributesName varchar(max),SourceTechAttributesValue varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'MediaFormat, FrameRate, DropFrame, StartSmpte','96, 29.97, False, 00:00:00:00')
,(2,'MediaFormat, NativeFrameRate, ActionType, ViewportDisplayFormat, ViewportAspectRatio, FrameRate, Width, Height, ScanType, FieldDominance, DropFrame, NativeFieldOrder, CadencePattern, NumberOfAudioChannels, NumberOfAudioTracks, StartSmpte, Duration','645, 23.98, Live Action, Anamorphic, 1.78:1 (16x9), 23.98, 1920, 1080, Progressive, Lower Field First, False, Progressive, 2-2, 12, 12, 00:59:35:00, 1507.380875')


Select *
 From  (
        Select A.ID
              ,B.*
         From  @YourTable A
         Cross Apply (Select Item  = concat('src',B1.RetVal)
                            ,Value = B2.RetVal
                       From  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](SourceTechAttributesName ,',') B1
                       Join  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](SourceTechAttributesValue,',') B2
                         on  B1.RetSeq=B2.RetSeq
                     ) B
       ) src
 Pivot (max(value) for Item in ([srcMediaFormat],[srcFrameRate],[srcDropFrame],[srcWidth],[srcHeight],[srcCodec],[srcDuration]) ) pvt
```

**Returns**

[image]

**To Help with the Visualisation, the Subquery Generates**

[image]

**The Parse/Split Function if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse]('this,is,<test>,for,< & >',',')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but unfortunately even I have implement your code i am getting error, I have executed that function and it creates a tabular function but as I have many columns  from joining from different tables so its giving me error,

Comment: @MHossain It was my understanding that the crux of the problem was that two seperate strings needed to be parsed and then linked up.  Sorry, but I can't speak to the different tables.

Comment: @MHossain  I have to ask.  What error are you getting?